# I have a bug in my vertical content slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My content slider doesn't always slide to the showing hash when i click on either of the buttons. i found out how to do this by watching this video Zhttps://www.lynda.com/jQuery-tutorials/Create-Interactive-Animated-Timeline-jQuery/124092-2.htmlZ (copy inbetween the Z's) then i learned the left and right slider controls on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrBuo3BZXlU&t=538s. however, my code seems to have a bug that sometimes stops it from going to the next or previous slide. heres the code

```
$('.right').click(function(event) {
    $('#showing').removeAttr('id').attr('id','wasShowing');
    $('#wasShowing').next().attr('id','showing');
    $('#wasShowing').removeAttr('id');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w3tkmhdn/1/

Can anyone see the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the scrollLeft part

```
$('.content-carousel').animate({
    scrollLeft: '+=' + $showing.offset().left
}, 800, );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w3tkmhdn/2/

for both left and right, for left, `$showing.offset().left` returns negative value so the `+=` works as is.

Comment: Thank you soooo much, this answer is perfect. I have had this problem for sooo long and couldn't find out what was wrong with the code, i literally created an account for this website today and asked for help and i am really impressed at how quickly i received advice. I very much appreciate this.